# Error with MPLAB X IDE v6.15. and compilator v2.45

Tags: mplab, mplab-c18, mplab-x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOks9.png)

I dont understand why this error appears. anyone could help me? and the compilator say that is not installed when its installed.

i tried Re-installing a lot and put the compilator and assembler manually (but doesnt work).